# not able to access and add product in admin site?-Django

Tags: python, django

i get this error in the browser

```
 Using the URLconf defined in myshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
       ^admin/ ^$ [name='index']
            ^admin/ ^login/$ [name='login']
            ^admin/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
            ^admin/ ^password_change/$ [name='password_change']
            ^admin/ ^password_change/done/$ [name='password_change_done']
            ^admin/ ^jsi18n/$ [name='jsi18n']
            ^admin/ ^r/(?P<content_type_id>\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$ [name='view_on_site']
            ^admin/ ^auth/group/
            ^admin/ ^auth/user/
            ^admin/ ^sites/site/
            ^admin/ ^(?P<app_label>auth|sites)/$ [name='app_list']
        The current path, admin/myshop/Product/add/, didn't match any of these.
```

i am basically a beginner to django and creating my django shop app. i get this error by typing the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myshop/Product/add/ My admin.py looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display=['name','slug']
prepopulated_fields={'slug':('name',)}
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class ProductAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
list_display=['name','slug','category','price','stock','avialable','created','updated']
list_filter=['available','created','updated','category']
list_editable=['price','stock','available']
prepopulated_fields=['slug':('name',)}
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
name = models.Charfield(max_length=200, db_index=True)
slug = models.Slugfield(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

class Meta:
ordering = ('name',)
verbose_name = 'category'
verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

def__str__(self):
return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class product(models.Model):
category=models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
name=models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
image=models.ImageField(upload_to'product/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
description=models.TextField(blank=True)
price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
stock=models.PositiveIntegerField()
available=models.BooleanField(default=True)
created=models.Datetimefield(auto_now_add=True)
updated=models.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
ordering=('-created',)
index_togetther=(('id','slug'),)

def__str__(self):
return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id,self.slug)
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

I tried to check everything but everything looks ok to me

Comment: post your urls, the main and also for the app

Comment: I don't understand why you've posted something that is clearly not your real code; you have errors like `Class` instead of `class` everywhere, this code wouldn't run. Not to mention the indentation errors.

Comment: changed the Class to class and corrected the identation errors, still not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your admin.py file
your model from the code you posted is having lowercase product class
but in admin you took capital Product, so change the Product to product

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, product

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display=['name','slug']
prepopulated_fields={'slug':('name',)}
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class ProductAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
list_display=['name','slug','category','price','stock','avialable','created','updated']
list_filter=['available','created','updated','category']
list_editable=['price','stock','available']
prepopulated_fields=['slug':('name',)}
admin.site.register(product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: Just login to admin panel and try to add product from the product. And check the url at top. That will be your original url. Dont put url directly in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands for migrating files:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `[`  or  `{`, that is:

```
prepopulated_fields***`=['`***slug':('name',)}
```

or

```
prepopulated_fields={'slug':('name',)}
```